# In a subset of cells, determine if at least one corresponding cell matches a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Given a table (spreadsheet) of two columns, for a subset of cells in column A that meet a particular criterion, determine if at least one of the corresponding cells in column B meet some other criterion.

For example, given the following data:

```
     A     B
1    DR    *
2    DR    &
3    SR    &
4    DR    *
5    SR    #
6    SR    #
```

I would like to know, for the subset of cells in column A that contain "DR", if there is at least one corresponding cell in column B that contains a "*".  So, then, for "DR" the answer is true, but for "SR" the answer is false.

I have looked at a variety of "count if two criteria match" answers on here, but that doesn't seem to be quite it. (Or, if it is, I don't see how to make those solutions work for my example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= CountIfs( A:A, "DR", B:B, "~*" ) > 0
```

`~` is needed just for any `*` or `?` characters.

[`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function